# Styling Div as shown in image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a div to be created this way shown in the image[image]

CSS code as follows :

/* Styles go here */

```
 .col-sm-3.widget_1_box {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.bg-success {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}

 .tile-progress {
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom:1em;;
}
```

I have created a div here in plnkr

```
<div class="widget_1">
             <div class="col-sm-3 widget_1_box">
                <div class="tile-progress musers">
                    <div class="newheader">
                        <h4><i class="topicname">Manage Users</i> </h4>
                       <!-- <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar inviewport animated visible slideInLeft" style="width: 40%;"></div></div>-->
                        <!--<span>40% increase</span>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/kMis2AGzSdKfc1Bhis3e?p=preview

Need assistance.

Comment: Please post the complete code with CSS which you've tried.

Comment: What is it exactly you need help with? If I had to hazard a guess, it would be the two parallelograms.

Comment: Posted CSS too. you can find the code in plnkr.

Comment: Th4n0s I need assistance in css to create similar kind of div attached in image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a linear gradient

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(110deg, #1e5799 50%, #663399 50%);
  height: 100px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  background: #1e5799;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(20, 67, 120, 1)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you , it is really helpful , can you assist me with giving a header row too .Where Manage user is given